# Windows server 2016 restart randomly after installing active directoy

Tags: active-directory, virtual-machines, windows-server-2016

I have a virtual machine with Windows Server 2016 on it, after installing active directory it starts to restart randomly.

- I tried installing windows from different sources.
- I tried in another host.

but the network was the same, this problem solves when I isolate the network (there is another active directory on the network).

any special log in event viewer except restarting suddenly.

I don't know,  any solution?!

this is mini dump file analyze:

> PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA (50) Invalid system memory was referenced.
>   This cannot be protected by try-except, it must be protected by a
>   Probe.  Typically the address is just plain bad or it is pointing at
>   freed memory. Arguments: Arg1: ffffe08f0d0da000, memory referenced.
>   Arg2: 0000000000000002, value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation.
>   Arg3: fffff8076b8b28b0, If non-zero, the instruction address which
>   referenced the bad memory     address. Arg4: 0000000000000000, (reserved)
>
> ### Debugging Details:
>
> Could not read faulting driver name TRIAGER: Could not open triage
>   file : e:\dump_analysis\program\triage\modclass.ini, error 2
>
> WRITE_ADDRESS: unable to get nt!MmSpecialPoolStart unable to get
>   nt!MmSpecialPoolEnd unable to get nt!MmPagedPoolEnd unable to get
>   nt!MmNonPagedPoolStart unable to get nt!MmSizeOfNonPagedPoolInBytes 
>   ffffe08f0d0da000
>
> FAULTING_IP:  srv!SrvOs2FeaToNt+48 fffff807`6b8b28b0 c60300
>   mov     byte ptr [rbx],0
>
> MM_INTERNAL_CODE:  0
>
> CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1
>
> DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT_SERVER
>
> BUGCHECK_STR:  AV
>
> PROCESS_NAME:  System
>
> CURRENT_IRQL:  2
>
> TRAP_FRAME:  ffff9081bdf026e0 -- (.trap 0xffff9081bdf026e0) NOTE: The
>   trap frame does not contain all registers. Some register values may be
>   zeroed or incorrect. rax=0000000000000000 rbx=0000000000000000
>   rcx=ffffe08f0d0da000 rdx=ffffa609828a109a rsi=0000000000000000
>   rdi=0000000000000000 rip=fffff8076b8b28b0 rsp=ffff9081bdf02870
>   rbp=ffffa609828a1095  r8=0000000000000000  r9=0000000000000000
>   r10=0000000000010000 r11=ffffe08f0d0da000 r12=0000000000000000
>   r13=0000000000000000 r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000 iopl=0 
>   nv up ei ng nz na po nc srv!SrvOs2FeaToNt+0x48: fffff807`6b8b28b0
>   c60300          mov     byte ptr [rbx],0 ds:00000000`00000000=00
>   Resetting default scope
>
> LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff801bfdb7945 to fffff801bfd666f0
>
> STACK_TEXT:   ffff9081`bdf023e8 fffff801`bfdb7945 : 00000000`00000050
>   ffffe08f`0d0da000 00000000`00000002 ffff9081`bdf026e0 :
>   nt!KeBugCheckEx ffff9081`bdf023f0 fffff801`bfcc47ba :
>   00000000`00000002 00000000`00000000 ffff9081`bdf026e0
>   00000000`00000200 : nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+0x41db5
>   ffff9081`bdf024e0 fffff801`bfd6fcfc : ffff84d3`00000000
>   fffff801`bfce0cfd 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 :
>   nt!MmAccessFault+0x9ca ffff9081`bdf026e0 fffff807`6b8b28b0 :
>   00003a85`6264534c 00000000`00000018 ffff9081`bdf02998
>   ffff9081`bdf02990 : nt!KiPageFault+0x13c ffff9081`bdf02870
>   fffff807`6b8b27f9 : ffffa609`828a1095 ffffe08f`0d0d9ff8
>   30513247`69414d62 ffffa609`828a1138 : srv!SrvOs2FeaToNt+0x48
>   ffff9081`bdf028a0 fffff807`6b8d3ec3 : ffffe08f`0e76ca60
>   00000000`00000000 ffffa609`82891010 ffffe08f`0f2c52c0 :
>   srv!SrvOs2FeaListToNt+0x125 ffff9081`bdf028f0 fffff807`6b8dcebe :
>   00000000`00000000 fffff807`00010fe8 ffffe08f`0d0c9010
>   ffffe08f`0e76ca60 : srv!SrvSmbOpen2+0xc3 ffff9081`bdf02990
>   fffff807`6b8e007b : ffffe08f`0e78fdb0 ffffa609`82891010
>   00000000`00000002 00000000`00001000 : srv!ExecuteTransaction+0x1be
>   ffff9081`bdf029d0 fffff807`6b86da4e : fffff807`00000000
>   00000000`00000000 ffffe08f`00000035 00000000`0000f3d0 :
>   srv!SrvSmbTransactionSecondary+0x40b ffff9081`bdf02a70
>   fffff807`6b86dc24 : ffffe08f`0e76ca60 00000000`00000000
>   ffffe08f`0e76d4d0 fffff807`6b878000 : srv!SrvProcessSmb+0x236
>   ffff9081`bdf02af0 fffff807`6b8aca36 : ffffe08f`0e8dd320
>   ffffe08f`0e76ca70 00000000`00000000 ffffe08f`0e76ca70 :
>   srv!SrvRestartReceive+0x114 ffff9081`bdf02b30 fffff801`c0150668 :
>   ffffa609`831884c0 ffffe08f`0ca9b700 ffffe08f`0f2c5180
>   00000000`00000080 : srv!WorkerThread+0x67a6 ffff9081`bdf02bb0
>   fffff801`bfc1e729 : a001030a`59840104 03020001`0208300a
>   0208300a`a160e316 3020a107`03020001 : nt!IopThreadStart+0x34
>   ffff9081`bdf02c10 fffff801`bfd6bbb6 : ffff9081`bbe80180
>   ffffe08f`0f2c5180 fffff801`bfc1e6e8 287e635c`b3596583 :
>   nt!PspSystemThreadStartup+0x41 ffff9081`bdf02c60 00000000`00000000 :
>   ffff9081`bdf03000 ffff9081`bdefd000 00000000`00000000
>   00000000`00000000 : nt!KiStartSystemThread+0x16
>
> STACK_COMMAND:  kb
>
> FOLLOWUP_IP:  srv!SrvOs2FeaToNt+48 fffff807`6b8b28b0 c60300
>   mov     byte ptr [rbx],0
>
> SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  4
>
> SYMBOL_NAME:  srv!SrvOs2FeaToNt+48
>
> FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner
>
> MODULE_NAME: srv
>
> IMAGE_NAME:  srv.sys
>
> DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  57cf9c45
>
> FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_AV_srv!SrvOs2FeaToNt+48
>
> BUCKET_ID:  X64_AV_srv!SrvOs2FeaToNt+48
>
> Followup: MachineOwner

Comment: Hi, please add some detail, we can’t help much if nothing is added

Comment: @yagmoth555 I added mini dump file analyze

Comment: Looks like SMBcrash (remote vuln) or bad memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server seem hit by a SMB vulnerability.

> srv!SrvSmbOpen2+0xc3 
> srv!SrvSmbTransactionSecondary+0x40b
>   
> srv!SrvRestartReceive+0x114

And you indirectly confirm me it at the same time;

> this problem solves when I isolate the network

Please close your SMB port. TCP 139, 445, UDP 137 and 138 and after to see the dropped packet afterhand to identify the culprit, please activate the firewall log (Select **Log dropped packets**), and check there after;

> %windir%\system32\logfiles\firewall\pfirewall.log

You will be able to trace back the problem.